# Error check on image/jpeg content type php file

Tags: php, image, jpeg

i have a php file with content type:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

This file works great with my localhost but when i uploaded it to my server it refuses to work so i'm trying to enable error checking on it but no errors display ever i guess cause of the content type, is there a work around this :s?

Thanks..

Comment: comment out the header declaration and see what the error message that results it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a script like

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
func1();
func2();
func3();
imagejpeg(....)
```

write your script like

```
<?php   
func1();
func2();
func3();
if ( noErrorCondition ) {
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg(....)
}
```

then add debug output as needed - or maybe even `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` (or keep an eye on php's [error.log](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log))